# accordion only works for 1st record

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

accordion declaration in `Site.Master`

```
  $(function () {
                $("#userList").accordion({ active: false });
     });
```

My View:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)  
   { %>  
       <h3><a href="#"><%: item.Key %></a></h3>  
       <div id="userList">  
    <% foreach (var docs in item.Value)
       { %>
           <h3><a href="#"><%: docs.Key %></a></h3>  

            <% foreach (var doc in docs.Value)
               { %>   

            <% } %>

     <%  } %>  

       </div>  
<% } %>
```

The first record has the accordion, subsequent records do not. Upon inspecting the elements
the first record has this class
`class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons"`

Not sure what I am failing to observe. Am using `aspx engine`

Page source:

```
<div id="body">

    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h2>Search Result</h2> <br />
                <h2>John doe</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <h3><a href="#">2222222</a></h3>  
        <div id="userList">  
            <h3><a href="#">Test1</a></h3>  
            <a href="http://somewhere">Testing1</a> <br />
        </div>  

       <h3><a href="#">123123123</a></h3>  
       <div id="userList">  
           <h3><a href="#">Testing2</a></h3>  
            <a href="http://sommewhere">Testing2</a> <br />
       </div>  

    </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html instead of the template

Comment: jsfiddle example would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, you have multiple elements with the id `userList`, use class attribute to group similar elements together. Also I would wrap the accordion body in a `div` element.

Also since you are using `active: false` you need to set `collapsible: true` also.

> Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the
>   collapsible option to be true.

```
<div id="body">

    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h2>Search Result</h2> <br />
                <h2>John doe</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <h3><a href="#">2222222</a></h3>  
        <div class="userList">  
            <h3><a href="#">Test1</a></h3>
            <div>
                <a href="http://somewhere">Testing1</a> <br />
            </div>
        </div>  

        <h3><a href="#">123123123</a></h3>  
        <div class="userList">  
            <h3><a href="#">Testing2</a></h3>  
            <div>
                <a href="http://sommewhere">Testing2</a> <br />
            </div>
        </div>  

    </section>
</div>
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $(".userList").accordion({ 
        collapsible: true, 
        active: false 
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvFhN/)

Comment: @SheikhHeera While I was preparing the fiddle I noticed some problem with the accordion display... I was fixing it... during that period I just marked it as deleted... otherwise it might attract negative votes

Comment: Make sense but I didn't see anything wrong in your answer, anyways.

Comment: @SheikhHeera it was related to setting the `active: false` property... see the update

Comment: Got, it, I didn't notice it, only obsessed with `ID` matter, lol!

Comment: @Arun P.Johny: Works like a charm. the class did the trick. if you have sample of a nested accordion, can you direct me to an answer your provided?

Comment: @user1361914 I don't recall anything... If you have a problem, please create a fiddle, I can try